# Why does adding data- attributes to JavaScript libraries prevent them from being aggregated?

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue with adding a data attribute to my preprocessed / aggregated javascript within my theme.

When I have preprocessing disabled, I am able to add a data attribute to individual files within the .libraries.yml file as suggested within the Drupal docs. `{attributes: {data-example-attribute: true}}`

However once I enable `['js']['preprocess'] = true;` to the settings.php file instead of my theme JS being aggregated into a single file they do not get aggregated at all.

Is there a hook that I'm missing which I could use to just prepend a data attribute onto the preprocessed JS file.

Using Drupal 9

Comment: What should happen to the attributes on a script tag that aggregates multiple files if two libraries specify different values for the same data- attribute?

Comment: @cilefen Thanks for your reply. In this instance all the files within the library require the same data attribute.

Comment: This issue seems like it is related, although if I am reading it right it could cause issues with `data-` attributes if merged, because it does not account for attribute values: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1587536